# capital letters string in R

Tags: r, string

I have character vector, where some of words starting with small letter, some with capital letter.
Which str function should I use to extract only those starting with capital letters?

Comment: Please read the information on how to ask a question at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.  In particular you need to provide a reproducible example that can be copied and pasted into R along with expected output.  You shouldn't assume that responders will create test cases for you in addition to answering the question.  The question should provide that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `stringr`

```r
vec <- c("This", "is", "A", "test", "Sentence", "a")

library(stringr)

vec[str_detect(vec, "^[[:upper:]]")]
#> [1] "This"     "A"        "Sentence"
```

Or using base r

```
grep("^[[:upper:]]", vec, value = TRUE)
#> [1] "This"     "A"        "Sentence"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>